# Python - dynamically create number of key:values in a new dictionary, based on given number of key:values from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic

I have a list of dictionaries that i get from my DB. each dictionary can have up to 4 value fields (depends on the number of group this item has). For example:

```
list_of_items = [
    {'name':'i am first','value_group_1':10, 'value_group_2':20},
    {'name':'i am second','value_group_1':20, 'value_group_2':40}
    {'name':'i am third','value_group_1':15, 'value_group_2':30, 'value_group_3':40},
    {'name':'i am forth','value_group_1':20, 'value_group_2':40, 'value_group_3':40, 'value_group_4':40},
]
```

My target is to create a dynamic dict per a given item i get.
For example if i get the first item I will want to yield:

```
item = list_of_items[0] # first item happen to have 2 groups
final_dict = {'calculated_value_g1':item.get('value_group_1')*100,
              'calculated_value_g2':item.get('value_group_2')*100}
```

And if i get the 4th item I will want to yield:

```
item = list_of_items[3] # forth item happen to have 4 groups
final_dict = {'calculated_value_g1':item.get('value_group_1')*100,
              'calculated_value_g2':item.get('value_group_2')*100,
              'calculated_value_g3':item.get('value_group_3')*100,
              'calculated_value_g4':item.get('value_group_4')*100}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start diving your logic into smaller pieces, loop through `list_of_items`, filter the `keys`, generate the new name of each `key`, calculate the new value, and finally build the `dictionary`, for example:

```
list_of_items = [
    {'name':'i am first','value_group_1':10, 'value_group_2':20},
    {'name':'i am second','value_group_1':20, 'value_group_2':40},
    {'name':'i am third','value_group_1':15, 'value_group_2':30, 'value_group_3':40},
    {'name':'i am forth','value_group_1':20, 'value_group_2':40, 'value_group_3':40, 'value_group_4':40},
]


def create_dict(d):
    output = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'name': continue

        new_key = f"calculated_value_g{k[-1]}"
        new_value = v * 100
        output[new_key] = new_value

    return output


results = [
    create_dict(d) for d in list_of_items
]

for d in results:
    print(d)

>>> {'calculated_value_g1': 1000, 'calculated_value_g2': 2000}
>>> {'calculated_value_g1': 2000, 'calculated_value_g2': 4000}
>>> {'calculated_value_g1': 1500, 'calculated_value_g2': 3000, 'calculated_value_g3': 4000}
>>> {'calculated_value_g1': 2000, 'calculated_value_g2': 4000, 'calculated_value_g3': 4000, 'calculated_value_g4': 4000}
```